# Trouble aligning x-axis Matplotlib (Homework)

Tags: python-3.x, csv, matplotlib, data-science, graphing

As stated about I have a homework assignment for a fundamentals of Data Science class.  I am filtering out  a tower with faulty information and plotting the data of the good tower by amplitude and timing.

The issue is with my mean line for my graph. It is suppose to run through the average of my points. Unfortunately I cannot seem to align across my X-axis.
My output looks like this: 
[image: Output Graph]

I've tried solution I've found on stack overflow, but the best I could come up was a mean line for the whole graph using:`mplot.plot(np.unique(columnOneF),np.poly1d(np.polyfit(columnOneF,columnTwoF,1))(np.unique(columnOneF)))`

```
import csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as mplot
import numpy as np

File = open("WhiteSwordfish_ch1.csv")
csv_file = csv.reader(File)

columnOneF = []
columnTwoF = []
columnThreeF = []
MeanAmp = []
Freq = []
TempFreq = []
last = 0

for row in csv_file:  # Loop graps all the rows out of the CSV File stores them by column in List
    if float(row[2]) == 21.312057:  # If statement check if the frequency if from the good tower if
        Freq.append(row)  # so it then grabs THE WHOLE ROW and stores in a a List

for row in Freq:  # Program loops through only the good tower's data and sorts it into
    columnOneF.append(float(row[0]))  # Seperate list by type
    columnTwoF.append(float(row[1]))
    columnThreeF.append(float(row[2]))




# Mean Line Calculation
for i in Freq:
    current = float(i[0])
    if current == last:
        TempFreq.append(float(i[1]))
    else:
        last = current
        MeanAmp.append(np.mean(TempFreq))
        # MeanAmp.insert(int(current), np.mean(TempFreq))
        TempFreq = []
print(MeanAmp)
print(columnOneF)

# Graph One (Filter Data)
# ****************************************************************************
mplot.title("Filtered Data")
mplot.xlabel("Timing")
mplot.ylabel("Amplitude")
mplot.axis([-100, 800, -1.5, 1.5])
mplot.scatter(columnOneF, columnTwoF, color="red")  # Clean Data POINTS
mplot.plot(MeanAmp, color="blue", linestyle="-")  # Line
# mplot.plot(np.unique(columnOneF),np.poly1d(np.polyfit(columnOneF,columnTwoF,1))(np.unique(columnOneF)))
mplot.show()  # Displays both graphs
```

Answer (score 1):

You have passed only `MeanAmp` to the `plot()` function, which is interpreted as

> `plot(y)`  # plot y using x as index array 0..N-1

[Source](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html)

If you provide x-cordinates, same as for the `scatter()` function, the lines will be aligned:

`mplot.plot(columnOneF, MeanAmp, color="blue", linestyle="-")`

Comment: I've tried that, but there aren't the same number of data points on the X-axis as there are on the Y-axis, and I throw an error. I think my best bet at the moment is to make a new list and every time I store a new Y mean value, store the corresponding X.

Comment: Indeed, you need equal length x and y arrays. Also, I suppose you would expect the mean line to be not shorter than you scatter plot. Which means, that if `MeanAmp` (y-coordinates) < `columnOneF` (x-coordinates), something is not right, and you may need to rethink the logic of your code. But this is the whole point of the homework and a completely different question, not related to your original question about why the mean line is so short. :)